# Error storing data into array, loop does not execute after first value iteration - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, arrays, express, for-loop, node-modules

Having trouble with a loop, please see this example:

```
// Example (This is what prints out in the console)

User Input: Hello,Stack Overflow  //stored as text[]

 var textbycomma = [] = text.toString().split(',');

textbycomma[] = ['Hello','Stack Overflow']
```

This is a loop to send the first message `(Hello)` entered by the user and then break out of the loop.

```js
for (let k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
  // I am unable to make it dynamic so let's take 2 as an example

  await dmb.page.waitForSelector(
    "a > div > div.Igw0E.rBNOH.YBx95.ybXk5._4EzTm.soMvl > div[class]"
  );

  await dmb.page.click(
    "a > div > div.Igw0E.rBNOH.YBx95.ybXk5._4EzTm.soMvl > div[class]"
  );

  await dmb.page.waitFor(2000);

  for (let i = 0; i < textbycomma.length; i++) {
    let type = textbycomma[i];

    await dmb.page.waitForSelector('textarea[placeholder="Message..."]');

    await dmb.page.type('textarea[placeholder="Message..."]', type, {
      delay: 100,
    });

    let ig = await dmb.page.$x('//button[contains(text(), "Send")]');

    await ig[0].click();

    await dmb.page.waitFor(2000);

    let readurls = [];

    readurls[i] = dmb.page.url();

    console.log(readurls);

    if ((i = textbycomma.length)) {
      break;
    }
  }

  await dmb.page.goto("https://page.com/page-example");
}

await dmb.browser.close();
```

Console outputs for:

```
for loop (i) = 0,0 // Prints zero both the times since it breaks out of the loop

readurls[i] = ['url1'] -- next iteration ['url2'] // it does not save url1 and url2 as a single array
```

I want to make it such that this `node.js` script runs at an interval of 1 hour, checking the array URLs and sending the second message `(Stack Overflow)` to them.